# How can I get the keyof a custom type declaration for NodeJS ProcessEnv?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have added a custom type declaration to **index.d.ts** file for processEnv as outlined below:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv extends IProcessEnv {
      SOME_VAR: string;
      SOME_OTHER_VAR: string
    }
}
```

I then have a function where I want to check that the string value for the property is on the ProcessEnv which I then attempted to use the keyof but it doesn't seem to validate the string as a valid key on ProcessEnv.

```
  type EnvTypes = keyof NodeJS.ProcessEnv;

  const someFunction = (envKey : EnvTypes) => {
     ...
  };

  someFunction('MY_VAR'); // This should show as red as its not on the interface
```

The intellisense works as expected showing the valid options but I am unable to validate the string passed as a valid key. How can this be achieved?

Comment: It seems that you could not find an answer for your question which is exactly what I want too, right?